# git + behat: No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'vendor/behat/gherkin'

Tags: git, behat

In my project i'm using git submodules.

I installed Behat using composer [method #1 from official doc] from app root.
All is working well.

But when now I do

```
git submodule init
```

or

```
update
```

i receive this

```
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'vendor/behat/gherkin'
```

In my app .gitmodules and /.git/config i've NOTHING speaking of gherkin.

What can I do ?

This problem is not blocking, but is due to behat because removing vendor folder the problem is no more here.

- I tried to delete .git subfolder from vendor/behat/gherkin but nothing changes
- If I remove vendor folder created after `php composer install` , then git warn me no more, so the problem I think is in tsome file inside of vendor folder, but I cannot find which
- I don't ask to an alternative solution (for example add vendor as submodule), I need a way to clean up the error

**i ALREADY read all of thread with title like "no submodule mapping" but noone can solve my problem** - **PLEASE DON'T MARK AS DUPLICATED**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is nothing in .gitmodules, it means that you have not added the submodule using git submodule add command.

Do something similar to the following:
git submodule add "external module path" "project directory"

After adding if you do git status, you should get .gitmodules configuration file which stores the mapping between project url and local directory.

Now if you read the contents of .gitmodules, it should list the mapping.

For more information please go through git submodules section in progit book (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Comment: All of content of vendor was installed using composer, it's NOT a submodule, we WANT to commit 'as is' and NOT use all of vendor subfolders. We already have some submodule, it's that the reason we do submodule init and/or submodule update, but we need to avoid the error, NOT to add vendor subfolders as modules